# Text suggestions on a contenteditable=true element

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, autosuggest, wysihtml5, suggestbox

I am using [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) (that is based on [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/)) amazing editor and it works fine and everyone is happy. But now I need to offer text suggestions when the user is typing something (like [this](http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest) or [this](http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/)). Those libraries expect a textarea and wysihtml5 uses an iframe with a `<body contenteditable="true">`.

All I need is some words to auto-complete (or open a popup with the suggestions) in some plain text inside the element.
Before I go deep in this, anyone has a suggestion of an library that could work inside an `contenteditable="true"` element?

**Edit 1:**
I created a basic lib that do what I need but I think I used all my poor js skills on this one... it works on a div with `contenteditable=true` but I'm having a hard time making it work on the wysihtml5 editor. Can some javascript/wysihtml5/rangy ninja give me some help?

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5UQfH/

**Edit 2:**
First working version: http://jsfiddle.net/X9jBM/1/

**Edit 3:**
slightly better (but not prettier) version (works with multiple editors on same page):
http://jsfiddle.net/X9jBM/18/
Still do not work fine when the suggestion are multiple words (it stops suggesting when there is a space)

Would still like to hear some feedback on this.

Comment: Multiple words do work actually on my system. This is a great addon. Go on with it.

Comment: Thanks! What I meant with the multiple words is like when I have the suggestions "blue dog" and "blue cat" - when I input "blue d" I do not get the suggestion. Next thing is to be able to TAB through the suggestions so this could be nice to have but i'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to integrate an existing solution like http://autocompletejs.com/?

Comment: I tried to use [jQuery.textcomplete](http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/) and [asuggest](http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest/) but both expect a TextArea... so for me it was easier to just start from scratch implementing only the basic that I needed (learned a little more js on the way too) autocomplete.js looks nice for more complex suggestions, maybe I will get some inspiration from them to my own lib :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a very simple and basic lib to do what I needed. It is not perfect nor tested in anything except the latest chrome version and I probably could eliminate the jQuery dependency quite easilly but since I already have it on my project (the old excuse), for now I will leave it as it is.
`ENTER` select a word and `TAB` cycle through the words.
http://jsfiddle.net/X9jBM/19/

The code:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
        return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
    };
}

var SuggestMe = function () {
"use strict";

var self = this;

return {
    init: init
};

function init(iframe, words) {

    self.list = [];
    self.currentIndex = 0;
    self.currentWord = "";
    self.$iframe = iframe;
    self.$editor = $(iframe).contents().find(".wysihtml5-editor");

    self.$editor.on("keydown", function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            var sel = rangy.getIframeSelection(self.$iframe);

            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.collapse(false);
                var textNode = document.createTextNode("  ");
                range.insertNode(textNode);
                sel.collapseToEnd();
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (event.keyCode === 9) {
            var sel = rangy.getIframeSelection(self.$iframe);
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
                self.currentIndex++;
                var word = self.list[self.currentIndex % self.list.length];
                var sel = rangy.getIframeSelection(self.$iframe);
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();
                var term = word.slice(self.currentWord.length, word.length);
                var textNode = document.createTextNode(term);
                range.insertNode(textNode);
                range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
                rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(range);

                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }

    });

    self.$editor.on("keyup", function (event) {

        var c = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        var isWordcharacter = c.match(/\w/);

        if (isWordcharacter && !event.ctrlKey) {

            var $editor = this;
            self.currentWord = getLastWord($editor);

            if (self.currentWord) {
                var sel = rangy.getIframeSelection(self.$iframe);

                if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
                    self.list = [];
                    self.currentIndex = 0;

                    $.each(words, function (a) {
                        var word = words[a].toLowerCase();

                        if (word.startsWith(self.currentWord.toLowerCase())) {
                            self.list.push(word);
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (self.list.length) {
                    var word = self.list[self.currentIndex];
                    var sel = rangy.getIframeSelection(self.$iframe);
                    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                    var term = word.slice(self.currentWord.length, word.length);
                    var textNode = document.createTextNode(term);
                    range.insertNode(textNode);
                    range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
                    rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(range);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


function getLastWord(elm) {
    var val = elm.innerText.trim();
    val = val.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ");
    var idx = val.lastIndexOf(' ');
    var lastWord = val.substring(idx + 1).trim();
    console.log(val);
    return lastWord;
}

};
```

The usage:

```
var suggestions = ["hello", "world", "blue dog", "blue cat"];

$('#txt').wysihtml5();
var editor = $('#txt').data("wysihtml5").editor;

editor.on('load', function () {
    var sm = new SuggestMe();
    sm.init(this.currentView.iframe, suggestions);
});
```

There is some refactor to be done but this is the basic idea.